# Symfony 1.4 - How can I remove a relation when querying

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Consider the following example

```
$q = Doctrine::getTable('User')->createQuery('u')
->where('u.username = ?', 'test');
```

If another related table exists (let's say a separate address table connected by username) this is also loaded in the results. How can I temporarily disable this relationship so that the query doesn't do any unnecessary joins? I don't want to remove it permanently because it's useful in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about that, The doctrine use lazy loading for relations, so the sql for join will only be executed when you fetch the relations.